# SimpleInjector throwing intermittent error on .Net MVC Site start up

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, simple-injector

I have an ASP.NET MVC which initializes Simple Injector in the Application_Start method.

The error appears intermittently during normal use of the site locally, and always disappears when the site is rebuilt in Visual Studio.  On deployment, the error appears immediately but can be made to go away by restarting the app on the server. After a little while it reappears.

The start up code is as follows:

```
public class CmsApplication : System.Web.HttpApplication
{
    private Container _container;
    private IQueryProcessor queryProcessor;

    private static ISiteManager _manager;
    public static ISiteManager SiteManager { get { return _manager; } }

    protected virtual void Application_Start()
    {
        // Mapping using AutoMapper
        CMS.UI.Client.Mapping.MappingConfig.RegisterMappings();

        // Initialize SimpleInjector
        InitializeIoC();

        AutoMapper.Mapper.AssertConfigurationIsValid();

        // Get query processor - this is used for handling database calls.
        queryProcessor = _container.GetInstance<IQueryProcessor>();

        // Get configuration
        IConfiguration configuration = CMS.Configuration.ConfigurationFactory.Get();

        // MVC Stuff
        AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
        RouteConfig routeConfig = new RouteConfig(queryProcessor);
        routeConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);

        FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);

        // Regular MVC startup
        AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();

        // Global SiteManager property. THIS COULD BE CAUSING THE ISSUE!
        _manager = _container.GetInstance<ISiteManager>();

    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Method to initialize the IoC Container
    /// </summary>
    protected void InitializeIoC()
    {
        // Initialize DI container
        _container = new Container();

        // Allows container to inject into filter constructors
        _container.RegisterMvcIntegratedFilterProvider();

        // Mapping
        _container.Register<AutoMapper.IMappingEngine>(() => (AutoMapper.IMappingEngine)AutoMapper.Mapper.Engine, Lifestyle.Singleton);
        _container.Register<IMapProcessor, MapProcessor>(); // Map Processor

        // Configuration
        _container.Register<IConfiguration>(() => (CMS.Configuration.Configuration)System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.GetSection("pipeline"), Lifestyle.Singleton);

        // Site Manager
        _container.Register<ISiteManager, SiteManager>(Lifestyle.Singleton);

        // Context and UnitOfWork Factories
        _container.RegisterPerWebRequest<IContext>(() => new CrmContext("Name=CrmContext"));

        // Context and UnitOfWork     
        _container.RegisterPerWebRequest<Pipeline.Core.Data.UnitOfWork.IUnitOfWork, Crm.UnitOfWork.EFUnitOfWork>();

        // Repositories
        _container.Register<ISiteRepository, SiteRepository>();
        _container.Register<IFolderRepository, FolderRepository>();

        // Sitemap
        _container.Register<ISitemapGenerator, SitemapGenerator>();

        // Robots
        _container.Register<IRobotsGenerator, RobotsGenerator>();

        // Command Handlers
        _container.RegisterOpenGeneric(
            typeof(IBatchCommandHandler<>), typeof(BatchCommandHandler<>));

        _container.RegisterManyForOpenGeneric(
            typeof(ICommandHandler<>),
            AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies());

        _container.RegisterManyForOpenGeneric(
            typeof(ICommandHandler<,>),
            AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies());

        // Validators
        _container.RegisterManyForOpenGeneric(
            typeof(IValidator<>),
            AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies());

        // Query Handlers
        _container.RegisterManyForOpenGeneric(
            typeof(IQueryHandler<,>),
            AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies());

        // Query Processor
        _container.Register<IQueryProcessor>(() => new QueryProcessor(_container));

        // Validation Decorators
        _container.RegisterDecorator(typeof(ICommandHandler<,>),
            typeof(ValidationCommandHandlerDecorator<,>),
            c => typeof(ICommandHandler<,>)
                    .MakeGenericType(c.ServiceType.GetGenericArguments())
                        .IsAssignableFrom(c.ImplementationType));


                    // Verify the container
        _container.Verify();

        //// Register the container as MVC IDependencyResolver
        DependencyResolver.SetResolver(new SimpleInjectorDependencyResolver(_container));

    }
```

The `InitializeIoC` method is just registration of the various types and nothing special.

After the `InitializeIoC` method, the `RouteConfig` call uses a database call using a type resolved through SimpleInjector. This appears to be fine.

The error seems to be being thrown when the _manager field is set as the resolved type uses `IQueryHandler<SiteQuery, ISiteInfo>` which is the source of the error. The ISiteManager is being set as a singleton by SimpleInjector, whether this is the source of the problem, I'm not sure.

The concrete handler is definitely present (as it does actually work, the bug is intermittent).

I'm a bit stumped on this!

Here is the error and stack trace:

> ## Error Page
>
> No registration for type IQueryHandler could be
>   found.    Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the
>   execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace
>   for more information about the error and where it originated in the
>   code.
>
> Exception Details: SimpleInjector.ActivationException: No
>   registration for type IQueryHandler could be
>   found.
>
> Source Error:
>
> An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the
>   current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of
>   the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.
>
> Stack Trace:
>
> [ActivationException: No registration for type
>   IQueryHandler could be found.]
>   SimpleInjector.Container.ThrowMissingInstanceProducerException(Type
>   serviceType) +136    SimpleInjector.Container.GetInstance(Type
>   serviceType) +76
>   Pipeline.Crm.Services.QueryProcessor.QueryProcessor.Pipeline.Core.Services.Queries.Interfaces.IQueryProcessor.Process(IQuery
>   query) in c:\Projects\Pipeline
>   CMS\Pipeline.CMS.Services\QueryProcessor\QueryProcessor.cs:29
>   Pipeline.CMS.UI.Client.Management.SiteManager..ctor(IQueryProcessor
>   queryProcessor, IConfiguration configuration) in c:\Projects\Pipeline
>   CMS\Pipeline.CMS.UI.Client\SiteManager\SiteManager.cs:23
>   lambda_method(Closure ) +148
>   SimpleInjector.Lifestyles.SingletonLifestyleRegistrationBase`1.CreateInstanceWithNullCheck()
>   +62    System.Lazy`1.CreateValue() +415    System.Lazy`1.LazyInitValue() +152    System.Lazy`1.get_Value() +75
>   SimpleInjector.Lifestyles.SingletonLifestyleRegistrationBase`1.BuildExpression()
>   +16    SimpleInjector.Registration.BuildExpression(InstanceProducer producer) +50
>
>   SimpleInjector.InstanceProducer.BuildExpressionInternal() +34
>
>   System.Lazy`1.CreateValue() +415    System.Lazy`1.LazyInitValue() +152
>   System.Lazy`1.get_Value() +75
>   SimpleInjector.InstanceProducer.BuildExpression() +55
>
> [ActivationException: The registered delegate for type ISiteManager
>   threw an exception. No registration for type IQueryHandler could be found.]
>   SimpleInjector.InstanceProducer.BuildExpression() +97
>   SimpleInjector.InstanceProducer.VerifyExpressionBuilding() +31
>
> [InvalidOperationException: The configuration is invalid. Creating the
>   instance for type ISiteManager failed. The registered delegate for
>   type ISiteManager threw an exception. No registration for type
>   IQueryHandler could be found.]
>   SimpleInjector.InstanceProducer.VerifyExpressionBuilding() +85
>   SimpleInjector.Container.VerifyThatAllExpressionsCanBeBuilt(InstanceProducer[]
>   producersToVerify) +28
>   SimpleInjector.Container.VerifyThatAllExpressionsCanBeBuilt() +127
>   SimpleInjector.Container.Verify() +109
>   Pipeline.CMS.UI.Client.CmsApplication.InitializeIoC() in
>   c:\Projects\Pipeline CMS\Pipeline.CMS.UI.Client\CmsApplication.cs:156 
>   Pipeline.CMS.UI.Client.CmsApplication.Application_Start() in
>   c:\Projects\Pipeline CMS\Pipeline.CMS.UI.Client\CmsApplication.cs:47
>   Pipeline.CMS.Client.MvcApplication.Application_Start() in
>   c:\Projects\Pipeline CMS\Banerjee.Web\Global.asax.cs:11
>
> [HttpException (0x80004005): The configuration is invalid. Creating
>   the instance for type ISiteManager failed. The registered delegate for
>   type ISiteManager threw an exception. No registration for type
>   IQueryHandler could be found.]
>   System.Web.HttpApplicationFactory.EnsureAppStartCalledForIntegratedMode(HttpContext
>   context, HttpApplication app) +9936825
>   System.Web.HttpApplication.RegisterEventSubscriptionsWithIIS(IntPtr
>   appContext, HttpContext context, MethodInfo[] handlers) +118
>   System.Web.HttpApplication.InitSpecial(HttpApplicationState state,
>   MethodInfo[] handlers, IntPtr appContext, HttpContext context) +172
>   System.Web.HttpApplicationFactory.GetSpecialApplicationInstance(IntPtr
>   appContext, HttpContext context) +336
>   System.Web.Hosting.PipelineRuntime.InitializeApplication(IntPtr
>   appContext) +296
>
> [HttpException (0x80004005): The configuration is invalid. Creating
>   the instance for type ISiteManager failed. The registered delegate for
>   type ISiteManager threw an exception. No registration for type
>   IQueryHandler could be found.]
>   System.Web.HttpRuntime.FirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +9915364 
>   System.Web.HttpRuntime.EnsureFirstRequestInit(HttpContext context)
>   +101    System.Web.HttpRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationPrivate(IIS7WorkerRequest
>   wr, HttpContext context) +254

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My first intuition is that the assembly that contains the query handler implementations isn't loaded yet at the time that `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies()`is called during the registration process. Your query handler implementations probably live in a different assembly than the `IQueryHandler<,>` interface does. Loading of assemblies can be a bit undeterministic in ASP.NET.

Instead of calling `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies()`, try specifying the assemblies directly as follows:

```
var assemblies = new[]
{
    typeof(SomeQueryHandlerImplementation).Assembly,
    typeof(SqlRepository<>).Assembly,
};

// Simple Injector v3.x
_container.Register(typeof(ICommandHandler<>), assemblies);
_container.Register(typeof(ICommandHandler<,>), assemblies);
_container.Register(typeof(IValidator<>), assemblies);
_container.Register(typeof(IQueryHandler<,>), assemblies);

// Simple Injector v2.x
_container.RegisterManyForOpenGeneric(typeof(ICommandHandler<>), assemblies);
_container.RegisterManyForOpenGeneric(typeof(ICommandHandler<,>), assemblies);
_container.RegisterManyForOpenGeneric(typeof(IValidator<>), assemblies);
_container.RegisterManyForOpenGeneric(typeof(IQueryHandler<,>), assemblies);
```

One small note about the registration of the `ValidationCommandHandlerDecorator` decorator. The registered predicate always returns true. The registration can therefore be simplified to the following:

```
_container.RegisterDecorator(typeof(ICommandHandler<,>),
    typeof(ValidationCommandHandlerDecorator<,>));
```